# How to generate a .DOC file in PHP with a Watermark

Tags: php, ms-word, .doc

Is this even possible? I know it's possible to generate watermarks in PHP. Also, is there a site with a list of HTML tags that can be used in a doc file? I'm basically wondering how far you can go in a DOC file with html before it breaks.

Comment: Word can act as an HTML editor, but why would you want to? It's got piss-poor support for anything "modern" in HTML, and its output barely qualifies as HTML even on a perfect day.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://phpword.codeplex.com/ It seems to have watermarks. I have't tried this one personally, but PhpExcel works great for me.